# Merge single cell data objects

Tags: merge, rna-seq

I have count matrices from the rhapsody platform that I turn into a singlecellobject using the function SingleCellExperiment.

I have multiple samples running over 2 batches that I'm merging using the scMerge function (without correction).
when merging samples from the same dataset it only merges identical genes that are present in the single (non-merged) datasets which makes me to drop from 25k to 10k unique genes.

Is there a way to circumvent this issue? Or do you think it would not affect downstream analysis since these genes will anyways be dropped after merging the two badges with Harmony?

the code I used for merging is the following

```
sce_list_batch1 <- list((S1), (S2), (S3), (S4), (S5), (S6)) 
sce_batch1<- sce_cbind(sce_list_batch1, method = "intersect", exprs = c("counts"), colData_names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

so I noticed it adds a batch correction by default. I have now added the piece cut_off_batch = 0 and it now includes all the genes